# Does happiness have any effect on anything in fallout shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

I don't like to see my vault dwellers be unhappy. Does it affect anything that I should be worried about? Give me suggestions on how to make their happiness go up.

Comment: A suggestion: remove the part asking for suggestions to up happiness, and post a seperate question simply asking how do I raise a vault dwellers happiness.

Answer (score 5):

Happiness impacts on your daily Vault Overseer review.

Every 24 hours, you recieve a rating, based off the general happiness of your dwellers.

Higher happiness ratings will reward more bottle caps.

Answer (score 4):

Over all Happy Dweller make production faster.
If you's average rate of happiness is 90-100% you will have the benefit of Food, Water, Power + 10% reduce in production time .
This benefit will be reduce 1% for each 10% of average happiness.

The easiest way to booth the happiness is to "get laid". The dweller who "get laid" will have 100% of happiness.

There are some reasons that make your dweller unhappy include: lack of food, have a dead body in the room. If you remove these factor the happiness will raise again.

Comment: It reduces production time? I always looked at it increased production rates. So when you collect resources, you gain a percentage more than you normally would.